# Failure to Authenticate to GIT hosted on TFS as an External Git Service Connection in Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines

As my work is making the transition between TFS and Azure Devops, we are in a position where we would like to start mananging all our dev's User Stories/Tasks/Bugs up in Azure Devops - along with the builds from our check-ins.

To get this setup we would like to first setup all our pipelines with the existing git repo's we have up on our TFS server.  But none of the service connection setup's I have tried are correctly authenticating.  The setup that appears to be working in other systems (tested with  an import into github) is to use username/PAT.
[image: Basic setup for GIT connection]

There is nothing unique to how this is setup on TFS. There is also no Verify button that sure would be a nice addition (Microsoft).

Running this on a pipeline creates this log.
[image]

The authentication portion of the url is also translating the @ in my email address to %AZP2540  so instead of having me@here.com:PAT it passes me%AZP2540here.com:PAT

Any help on how to get past this, would be a big help.

**UPDATE:**
Switching over to HTTPS allowed me to import the repository with a username and PAT.  The same setup has not worked for an External GIT Service Connection.

Comment: You can leave the username empty or simply use `.`. only the PAT matters.

Comment: But more importantly, since TFS can be upgraded to Azure DevOps in a short amount of time, why do you want to run the projects side-by-side?

Comment: @jessehouwing - leaving the username blank changes the url to  http://emptyusername:***  and using . for the username has the same Authentication Failed error.  I belive there was an internally identified issue with upgrading straight from TFS to Azure Devops that prevented us from switching.

Comment: Looks like the target TFS is running http. By default PAT access is disabled on non-secure protocols. Cause the PAT is sent cleartext over the wire.

Comment: I thought that might be an issue.  In an effort to test an external connection, I was able to get a connection for an import into a github repo - but maybe github is more lax on what they allow.

Comment: So, its not https either.  Changed everything over and still cannot authenticate.  I feel like this is an Azure Devops issue.

Comment: Where did you create the PAT? This feature normally just works, you can see in the logs what commands get run. Do they work when you manually execute those commands on the agent?

Comment: PAT was created in TFS where GIT is hosted.  PAT works for importing into azure and github like previously mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to configure a service connection of type
**Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server**
with access to the project and include that in YAML ,
not in the type of git